# Error response from daemon: client version 1.40 is too new. Maximum supported API version is 1.39

Tags: docker

After installing docker 19.03.09, any docker command involving the docker daemon is throwing the following error.

```
Error response from daemon: client version 1.40 is too new. Maximum supported API version is 1.39
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is known issue with docker client 19.03.09. It happens if the daemon version supports only max api-version 1.39. Client is not downgrading the API version to match the server supported version automatically. It should be fixed in 19.03.10.

https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2533

As a workaround, you can set the docker api version using following environment variable.

```
export DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.39
```

Comment: I had the same issue with docker client `24.0.2-rd` and the client API version was `1.43` and the server version was `1.41`. The same solution worked for me `export DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.41`